# Images with symmetry parameters

Tags: images, programming

I wrote a program that searches for aesthetic pictures.
One of my parameters is how much a picture is symmetrical.

[image]

This picture is taken from 33Pol (from Iran-Isfahan). As can be seen, the water reflection causes a certain symmetry.

Is there any free or public database containing images + rates for aesthetics + symmetry parameters for this purpose?

For example in [this page](http://www.dpchallenge.com/challenge_results.php?CHALLENGE_ID=2428) you can see votes but there are no parameters for symmetrical properties.

Comment: I find it difficult to understand the kind of symmetrical properties you are looking for. Could you possibly show a few examples of images and the score you assign to them, and why?

Comment: Babak, I have cleaned up your question (including your reply to Grimaldi). You still need to answer Swiers question about the kind of symmetry. And please [read this](http://meta.opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look-like) and improve your question further.